# How should a function in R be for calculating Krackhardt E/I Ratio?

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I am working with the igraph package and the measure is actually a relative proportion of external ties to all ties an actor has. By external ties I mean the ties that ego has with alters from other groups than his own (a vertex attribute that indicates group belonging  exists in the object).

The formula should be (E-I)/(E+I). The part I miss to grasp is also how to get this value at the group level, such that each group has an E/I index.

Comment: an example or a snapshot of your data and how it is organized would be extremely helpful.

Comment: at this point my data  is an igraph object, but the network data is a one mode matrix with cells having values of 0 (where there is no tie between actor i and j) and 1 where there is a tie. As I mentioned, the group to which an actor belongs to is stored as a vertex attribute in the igraph object but it can be easily extracted as a vector.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

To help us help you, it is common and recommended that you provide actual code/data as example. I'll try to overcome this.
suppose the adjacency matrix and grouping are:

```
am = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))

g = factor(c(1,1,2,2,3))
```

let's first count the edges by group for each node

```
eg = aggregate(am,list(g),sum)
eg1 = t(as.matrix(eg[,-1]))
```

Now, let's compute E and I:

```
I = eg1[cbind(1:5,as.integer(g))]
E = rowSums(eg1)-I
```

And your measure:

K = (E-I)/(E+I)

I hope this helps

Comment: It actually didn't work. I had an error from the aggregate function "arguments must have same length".

Comment: I fixed that . And while applying on my data (which is a non-symmetric matrix now) I have more of a substantive question: when creating that aggregated sum, it considers the relation from the perspective of the vertex on the rows or on the columns? In your data, that is not a problem.But when having  directed ties it makes a difference in interpretation. Thanks